# Where is significant white space in pandoc/markdown usually regulated?

Tags: css, markdown, pandoc

I'm using pandoc to convert some markdown documents to .html via a custom css file.

Everything is working except one thing. From what I understand the text in  ``` backticks `` ``` should be white space significant, since it is usually code inside. In my case, it is not - in other words, it just looks like ordinary other text.

***I'm interested in where is that regulated in pandoc, or in a custom css file - what css attribute regulates whether the white space should be significant?***

Answer (score 4):

Pandoc will put text between backticks inside HTML `<code>` tags.  Leading and trailing whitespace are ignored (as in Markdown.pl), but internal spaces are preserved.  Newlines are treated as spaces.  Check the HTML source to make sure you have the `<code>` tags. If you don't, then there is probably a problem with your markdown source.  Also check to make sure you're not linking to CSS that overrides the default settings for `<code>` tags.

Comment: I'm using a custom css file, and it doesn't seem to be preserving blanks. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

The css property you're looking for is `white-space`.

I was having the same problem, and it was because of this css:

```
pre {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

To fix it I added `white-space: pre-wrap;` to the `code` rule:

```
code {
  font-family: "Menlo", "Courier New", "Courier", monospace;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  border: 0.0625rem solid rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  border-radius: 2px; color: #2DAB5F; /* #2DAB5F */
  text-shadow: none;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

You can see all of the [white-space options here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp).

The two you're probably interested in are:

> **`pre`**: Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will only wrap on line breaks. Acts like the  tag in HTML
>
> **`pre-wrap`**: Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks

The css I'm using has a max width, so it's not uncommon for line wrapping to happen. I preferred `pre-wrap`, which wraps on words, as opposed `pre` which will wrap in the middle of a word.